# How can I easily select an enemy colony with a large space station in orbit?

Tags: distant-worlds-shadows

I would like to select a enemy planet to have a look at the troops stationed there. Usually this is possible, but in my case there's a large space port in orbit of the planet.

Now whenever I try to select the planet by clicking on it, I select the spaceport instead. How can I select the planet?

The below screenshot shows the problem, this large spaceport is completely covering the selectable planet area:
[image: Space port covering planet]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had this happen to me before and it's very annoying. Right-clicking will open a drop-down menu and the enemy planet should be included in the selections. Alternatively, you can zoom out, select the solar system and then select colonized planets.